# How to pass Object as a generic function parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to write a function which takes whichever Object as a parameter, iterate through its properties and write it all to the console. Here is an example:

**Equipment.cs**

```
    public class Equipment
    {
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
```

**People.cs**

```
    public class People
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age{ get; set; }
    }
```

Here is example of what I return to above models from API:

```
   var equipment_res = responseObject?.items?.Select(s => new Equipment
       {
          SerialNo = s.serial_number,
          ModelName = s.model.name,
       });

   var people_res = responseObject?.items?.Select(s => new Equipment
       {
          SerialNo = s.serial_number,
          ModelName = s.model.name,
       });
```

And now I'm struggling to write a function which can take any object and writes its properties to the console. I don't know how to properly pass objects to function in this case:

```
        public void WriteProps(Object obj1, Object obj2)
        {
                foreach (Object obj1 in obj2)
                {
                    Object obj1 = new Object();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo p in obj1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(obj1, null));
                    }
                }
        }
```

Function call:

```
WriteProps(Equipment, equipment_res)
```

**EDIT:** below there's a working example but when I explicitly pass named object. It works fine but now I would like to make this function more genric:

```
   foreach (Equipment item in equipment)
   {
         Equipment eq = new Equipment();
         eq = item;

         foreach (PropertyInfo p in eq)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
             Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(eq, null));
         }
   }
```

Comment: Why doesn't a JSON or XML serializer supply your needs?

Comment: `foreach (PropertyInfo p in obj1)`   You need to get the property definition by reflection. You should check this [Viewing Type Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/viewing-type-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your method generic and then use reflection ([System.Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=net-6.0)):

```
void WriteProps<T>(T obj)
{
    foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(obj));
    }
}
```

Use:

```
WriteProps(new People
{
    Name = "Test",
    Age = "11"
});
WriteProps(new Equipment
{
    ModelName = "test",
    SerialNo = "test"
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I'd add this method to work with IEnumerable objects:

```
void WritePropsList<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        WriteProps(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but what if I want to pass second object e.g. `equipment_res` (as I showe in my post) where I store API result? I edited my post and added working example of code where I iterate over both objects e.g. `Equipment` and `equipment_res`. How to make function generic taking both into account?

Comment: as I understood the first parameter of your method indicates type of object and the second parameter is some list of this object type right?

Comment: "_make your method generic_" Why does it need to be made generic?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay because the second parameter is IEnumerable and it is better to get information from object without boxing. It is just my opinion, maybe I am wrong and I'd get any recommendations about my answer :)

Comment: Yes, it can be used with value types without boxing. I would add that to the answer, because there's no technical reason why you cannot simply pass `object`. It also introduces the possibility of doing `WriteProps<Base>(new Derived());` which would omit the derived properties (this may or may not be desirable).